# javascript is not available in rendered js partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am facing such problem:
On a page I render a js partial (ajax), this partial contains some fields. Also I have a file with js code which should make something when I focus on a field with class 'expand'. 
The problem is: **this script works for all fields with class 'expand' on the page except fields rendered in a partial**. How do you thing what could be a problem?
file.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.expand').focus(function () {
      alert('hello');
    });
  });
});
```

I render a js partial:

```
$("#tasks-right").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'task_details', :locals => {:object => @task}) %>");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use unobtrusive JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('focus', '.expand', function() {
    alert('hello');
  });
});
```

Also, this lines of code doing the same things:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
```

So drop the first one and keep just the second like in my example above.